# valid kernel functions for SVM

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I am implementing SVM with the following kernel functions:

assume a and b are scalars:

1. k(a,b) = (a-b)^4
2. k(a,b) = alpha * ab,   alpha >=0
3. k(a,b) = (ab+1)^4

are these valid kernels?

Thanks for help! :)

Comment: At least, 2, 3 are valid. they are polynomial kernel functions. This question is off-topic. You'd better asking on http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

2 and 3 are just a specific polyonmial kernels `K(a,b)=(alpha*<a,b>+c)^p` while the first one is not a valid scalar product as `K(a,a)=0` which would imply that for each `x`, `phi(x)=0`, so this would imply that for all `a,b,c,d`, `K(a,b)=K(c,d)` (in other words, the kernel is **constant**, which is not true, contradiction).